# applying code to text lines instead of container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code which scrolls the the content at different speeds

```js
$.fn.moveIt = function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var instances = [];

  $(this).each(function() {
    instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
  });

  window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    instances.forEach(function(inst) {
      inst.update(scrollTop);
    });
  }
}

var moveItItem = function(el) {
  this.el = $(el);
  this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
};

moveItItem.prototype.update = function(scrollTop) {
  this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -(scrollTop / this.speed) + 'px)');
};

// Initialization
$(function() {
  $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 data-scroll-speed="3">text 1</h1>
<p data-scroll-speed="5">text 2 .... content covers multiple lines full parapgraph</div>
```

The code works to scroll each piece at a different 'speed,' but I want it to apply to each line in the content. (so each line in the content scrolls at a different speed)

EDIT: the content isn't hardcoded, its generated through the wordpress admin/user

Comment: You should put different lines in different `<span>`s or `<p>`s in order to manipulate them differently. These elements should be populated dynamically using javascript and adjusted upon resize.

Comment: Problem is the text isn't hardcoded into the site (writtn on the developers admin side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought if each line is dynamically put into a different `<span>` would solve the problem. A nice start for you:

```js
$("p").each(function(i) {
  var pContent=$(this).text();
  $(this).html("<span id='line"+i+"-0'><span>");
  var lineID=0;
  while (pContent.length>0) {
    var firstSpace=pContent.indexOf(" ")+1;
    if (firstSpace==-1) firstSpace=pContent.length;
    var originalData=$("#temp-span").text();
    $("#temp-span").append(pContent.substring(0,firstSpace));
    if ($("#temp-span").width()>$(".container").width()) {
      $("#line"+i+"-"+lineID).text(originalData);
      $("#temp-span").text("");
      $(this).append("<span id='line"+i+"-"+(++lineID)+"'></span>");
    } else {
      pContent=pContent.substring(firstSpace,pContent.length);    
    }
  }
  if ($("#temp-span").text().trim()!="") {
    $("#line"+i+"-"+lineID).text($("#temp-span").text());
    $("#temp-span").text("");
  }
});
  $("pre").text($(".container").html());
```

```css
#temp-span {
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

span {
  display: block;
}

pre {
  white-space: normal;
  background-color: #8ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi mattis lacinia dui sit amet dapibus. Curabitur nec mi tellus. Nullam posuere auctor justo, vel ornare odio malesuada vitae. Sed ullamcorper libero sit amet est posuere, sed cursus metus tristique. Vestibulum varius erat at mi dapibus, quis scelerisque leo tempor. In auctor maximus tempus. Sed sed tristique est, nec auctor nulla. Aenean et porttitor ex, ac malesuada ipsum. Quisque sit amet urna pulvinar libero scelerisque maximus. Morbi ac tincidunt libero. Donec tempus suscipit hendrerit. Nulla et purus ultricies, eleifend augue vitae, egestas odio. Pellentesque ante libero, pulvinar quis orci quis, sodales tincidunt libero. Sed volutpat purus diam, quis gravida lacus commodo quis. Nunc interdum metus at condimentum gravida. Ut vulputate est non ultrices maximus.
  </p>
  <p>
  Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean pharetra dignissim mattis. Cras purus risus, accumsan a sapien eu, ultricies dictum diam. In hendrerit, erat efficitur sodales tristique, purus sapien dignissim magna, non vulputate dolor tellus vestibulum sapien. Suspendisse ullamcorper dolor sit amet nisl vulputate, vitae condimentum nunc sodales. Pellentesque ut ullamcorper quam. Quisque et mauris lacus. Suspendisse commodo facilisis mi. Suspendisse sit amet metus felis.
  </p>
  <span id="temp-span"></span>
  <h4>Code:</h4>
  <pre></pre>
 </div>
```

Comment: Ohh, I must have miss-understood, I just meant I don't have control over what gets typed, it's generated by the wordpress admin panel